# General solution of $xy '= y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the folowing differential equation:
$$xy '= y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

---

I try to solve it 
this my result: $\sqrt{v^2 +1}+v=x+c$ where $c$ is  a constant.
I don't know if its correct or not !

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $$y(x)=x\cdot v(x)$$ then you will get
$$\frac{dv(x)}{dx}=\frac{\sqrt{v(x)^2+1}}{x}$$